# Flutter Launcher getting system applications

Tags: dart, flutter, android-launcher

I'm building a costum launcher for Android in flutter(I know it's not the best idea), and I'm currently struggling because I cannot get all of the installed applications in my applications list.

To get the applications i use the `launcher_assist` plugin with the following code:

```
void loadApps() {
    LauncherAssist.getAllApps().then((_appDetails) {
      setState(() {
        installedAppDetails = _appDetails;
      });
    });
  }
```

But the code doesn't show applications like settings, camera or Google Drive.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You should probably write to [Ahsraff](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/launcher_assist)..

Comment: Ok, ty for the tip, I did message him. But maybe somebody else knows how to solve the problem...